# Modify WooCommerce Is_Purchasable

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I was working on implementing my own pre-order system, where I set a `is_preorder` custom field for each product.

I was trying to modify the WooCommerce's `Is_Purchasable` option so that, if the product has pre-order status **and** it's already passed the pre-order deadline, it shouldn't be able to be purchased. I've tried a bunch of ways, but nothing seems working.

Here's something that I did (rough idea)

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'preorder_is_purchasable');

function preorder_is_purchasable() {

    // this is a field added using 'Advance Custom Fields' plugin 
    $is_preorder = get_field('is_preorder'); 

    if($is_preorder && "not yet passed deadline")
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

I don't just wanna disable the `add_to_cart` button, I also want to disable the functionality (should prompt error if user tried to add product by hardcoding in url).
How should I go on with this?

===========================================================================

Here's my final code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'preorder_is_purchasable', 10, 2);

function preorder_is_purchasable( $is_purchasable, $object ) {

// this is a field added using 'Advance Custom Fields' plugin 
$is_preorder = get_field('is_preorder', $object->id); 

// if product is Pre-Order
if($is_preorder)
{
    $today = date('Ymd');

    // another field added using 'Advance Custom Fields' plugin 
    $preorder_deadline = get_field('preorder_deadline', $object->id); 

    if($today <= $preorder_deadline) // if not yet pass deadline
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
else
    return $is_purchasable; // normal
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***Update 2019***: please see [dev_masta answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259052/modify-woocommerce-is-purchasable/48177212#48177212) for correct solution nowadays.

---

Not sure if it solves the issue as this has to be tested on your own custom set up. But you're using `get_field` wrong: if it is not used inside a Loop, [you should provide the post ID](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field/).

Analyzing the filter `woocommerce_is_purchasable`, we see that [it takes two parameters](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product_Grouped.html#151), a boolean (`is_purchasable`) and an object (WC_Product).

Try this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'preorder_is_purchasable', 10, 2);

function preorder_is_purchasable( $is_purchasable, $object ) {

    // this is a field added using 'Advance Custom Fields' plugin 
    $is_preorder = get_field('is_preorder', $object->id); 

    if($is_preorder && $is_purchasable)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That totally helps me to get things work. Very helpful. You're awesome!! :D

I think now I have better idea to work on the filter hook.

Comment: @NabilZhafri, glad it helped :) Check this article too: http://ottopress.com/2011/actions-and-filters-are-not-the-same-thing/

Comment: Although this still works, it's not used correctly because it throws a notice: `PHP Notice:  ID was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. Product properties should not be accessed directly.` - besides that, the link in the comment before mine is obviously connected to some updated code without the filter in question.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is a bit outdated today.

Instead of using `$object->id` you should use `$object->get_id()`, otherwise you'll get a PHP notice about incorrect use.

```
function disable_purchased_products( $is_purchasable, $object ){

    // custom function to get the array of purchased products ID's
    $already_purchased = get_purchased_products();

    if( in_array( $object->get_id(), $already_purchased ) ){
        return false;
    } else {
        return $is_purchasable;
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'disable_purchased_products', 10, 2 );
```

I hope this will help someone, I've seen this (outdated) code all around the net..

Comment: I've used this snippet, but I don't know is is getting $object from other product, not the one that is showing...

Comment: I don't know how this could be the case - the `woocommerce_is_purchasable` hook is called by woocommerce itself, and it should contain the object `$object` of the product in question. The point of my answer here was only to show that you should use `$object->get_id()` instead of `$object->id`. You can't use this snippet as is, because there's a custom function `get_purchased_products()` within, which is not listed here.

Comment: I've added a notice on my answer pointing to yours. *"I've seen this...all around the net"*, lol, SO reach is impressive, this question has about ~3 daily views since 6 years ago.